# Error in crawler JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a problem with a crawler test (spidering) in JMeter, I also have native code in java it does not work because I need to send a parameter in POST called javax.faces.ViewState

I just need to circumvent that parameter, then I leave my code in Java and based on your opinion would be more feasible for a crawler (spidering).

enter image description here
[image error in JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcARr.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://appware-sst.com/elegancia-ejecutiva")
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")

        .execute();

        Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://appware-sst.com/elegancia-ejecutiva/php/inicio_admin.php")
        .data("user", "admin")
        .data("password", "12345")                           
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .post();





        System.out.println(document);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to use escape sequence character \ in the regular expression. E.g. value\=\"(.+?)\"

Please try with escape sequence and let me know if that worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it did not work for me, in the java code I already manage to bring the html and its data, but for the site I'm working on it does not work for me by javax.faces.ViewState I can not predict it by any means.
In JMeter I still marked error and can not make a successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your Regular Expression I don't think you need this `!` in it.

Also depending on your server response you may get in multi lined, having other tag in between `name` and `value`, etc. so I would recommend getting the value using [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead, the relevant configuration would be:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `viewState`
- XPath query: `//input[@name='javax.faces.ViewState']/@value`

JMeter should fit better as it supports cookies, headers, cache, reporting. out of the box, moreover you can use [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for quickly building your test skeleton.

You may also find [How to Spider a Site with JMeter - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-spider-site-jmeter-tutorial) useful as you can build a crawler using [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) test element only.